# How do I create an in-app settings view?

Tags: objective-c, ios, cocoa-touch, xcode4.3

I want to create an in-app setting view like the following image:

[image: settings screenshot]

What are these fields called? and what is the best way to create settings?

I found many tutorial but all of them are referring to creating the settings page in the phone settings, using the setting bundle and what I want is creating settings page in the app itself.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Both http://www.inappsettingskit.com and http://inscopeapps.com/#inappsettings both use the standard Settings.app bundle. So you have the ability to set defaults in your app AND in the standard Settings.app. They're simple enough to add your project and work pretty well.

If you only want the settings to be in the app, then your screen shot simply shows a standard `UINavigationController` with `UITableViews`. You can create something like this in the standard ways using Interface Builder or programatically, and then respond to any changed settings by saving `NSUserDefaults` objects/integers/booleans/URLs.

Whichever method you choose, add an observer for `NSUserDefaultsDidChangeNotification` in any views that need to respond instantly to the change (you can simply read the current value of the `NSUserDefaults` objects/integers/booleans/URLs in real time if you don't need something to respond instantly).

Answer (score 0):

Try using In App Settings Kit.

Can be found here:  http://www.inappsettingskit.com